# How can I identify a dhs and xml response in a Splunk search?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

An issue I need to solve is getting the count for merchants and acquirers using dhsiso,dhsrest,dhssoap and dhsxml. iso and soap are simple enough but I am not sure how to approach xml or rest.

I tried to search by checking the logs for the word rest or xml but I am sure a better way exists. This is my current code for iso and soap.

```
sourcetype=dhs-*
| stats values(acquirer_id) as AcquirerCount, values(merchant_id) as MerchantCount by sourcetype
| stats sum(AcquirerCount) as TotalAcquirerCount, sum(MerchantCount) as TotalMerchantCount by sourcetype
```

Comment: what have you already tried? Your say "iso and soap are simple enough", but don't show what you've done to find those.  What does your data look like? Also, `values(qcquirer_id)` is not going to give you a number that can then be `stats sum()`d